# Overriding two forms sharing the same CSS sheet in HTML5

Tags: css, html, forms, overriding

I've checked other topics here on overriding, and can't seem to find a way to fix this one.

I have two .html files sharing the same .css. One has a text form for emailing questions. The other is just a basic radio button list. The problem is, they're sharing the text form's CSS style. The way I have it now, the text for each radio button appears below the radio button. But if alter the .css's input, textarea code, it messes up the text form... but the radio buttons appear as they should.

I've tried several methods to override it, and nothing seems to work. Guess I better break out the code...

*html 1*

```
    <form class="form" method="post" action="http://webdevbasics.net/scripts/demo.php">
        <label for="uName">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="uName" id="uName">
        <label for="uEmail">E-mail:</label>
        <input type="text" name="uEmail" id="uEmail">
        <label for="uQuestion">Question(s):</label>
        <textarea for="uQuestion" id="uQuestion" rows="10" cols="50">
        </textarea>
        <input id="uSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
```

*html 2*

```
    <form name="ffFave" method="post" id="order" action="ff.php">
        <b>irrelevant flavor text<p>
        <input type="radio" name="faveff" id="fave1" value="FF1">Option 1<br>
        <input type="radio" name="faveff" id="fave2" value="FF2">Option 2<br>
        <input type="radio" name="faveff" id="fave3" value="FF3">Option 3<br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

*CSS*

```
    form {background-color: #a09da9;
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  padding: 15px;}

  input, textarea (margin-top: 10px;
            display: block;)
```

Now I know the culprit is the display: block. I've tried to override it based on examples I've seen posted here, and other sources, but none of the methods I've tried... classes, overrides, all the basic textbook CSS... nothing will make that block display shut up on the radio options.

What do I need to do? Am I just looking at this too hard, or is there something I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the radio elements style in this way:

```
form {
  background-color: #a09da9;
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  padding: 15px;
}

input, textarea {
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: block;
}

input[type=radio] {
  /* Whatever code you want to override, like display: inline */
}
```

Comment: THIS. I've NEVER seen an override like this in my textbook or anything else I tried to dig up. Works perfectly now, thank you Alvaro.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to specify a new rule for radio button only which will override the input style --> use **attribute** and element selectors:

```css
   form {
     background-color: #a09da9;
     font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
     padding: 15px;
   }
   input,
   textarea {
     margin-top: 10px;
     display: block;
   }
   input[type=radio] {
     display: inline;
   }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="c.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
</head>

<body>
  <form class="form" method="post" action="http://webdevbasics.net/scripts/demo.php">
    <label for="uName">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="uName" id="uName">
    <label for="uEmail">E-mail:</label>
    <input type="text" name="uEmail" id="uEmail">
    <label for="uQuestion">Question(s):</label>
    <textarea for="uQuestion" id="uQuestion" rows="10" cols="50">
    </textarea>
    <input id="uSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>

  <form name="ffFave" method="post" id="order" action="ff.php">
    <b>irrelevant flavor text<p>
        <input type="radio" name="faveff" id="fave1" value="FF1">Option 1<br>
        <input type="radio" name="faveff" id="fave2" value="FF2">Option 2<br>
        <input type="radio" name="faveff" id="fave3" value="FF3">Option 3<br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to override some style, you must write some style that has higher priority. Following are the rules to compute the priority value:

- count 1 if the declaration is from is a 'style' attribute rather than a rule with a selector, 0 otherwise (= a) (In HTML, values of an element's "style" attribute are style sheet rules. These rules have no selectors, so a=1, b=0, c=0, and d=0.)
- count the number of ID attributes in the selector (= b)
- count the number of other attributes and pseudo-classes in the selector (= c)
- count the number of element names and pseudo-elements in the selector (= d)
- The specificity is based only on the form of the selector. In particular, a selector of the form "[id=p33]" is counted as an attribute selector (a=0, b=0, c=1, d=0), even if the id attribute is defined as an "ID" in the source document's DTD.

Concatenating the four numbers a-b-c-d (in a number system with a large base) gives the specificity.